# how to show indicator for current playing queueitem in mediabrowserservice (android auto) android?

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowserservice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBdjl.png)

i want to show indicator icon like above image

I will try lots of but i havent idea. how to do it like this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the `setActiveQueueItemId` method as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#required-actions)?